# Java: A string for Class out of while loop? How?

Tags: java

Hello i want to use strings out of a while loop for further operations.. but how do i "extract" them ot of the while loop?

I want to use sollWert1,sollWert2,sollWert3,sollWert4.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br = null;

        String file_at_path_to_desktop = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\" + "Desktop" + "\\" + "SollAuftrag.txt";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file_at_path_to_desktop)));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(";");
                String sollWert1= parts[0];
                String sollWert2= parts[1];
                String sollWert3= parts[2];
                String sollWert4= parts[3];
                System.out.println("Wert1: " + sollWert1);
                System.out.println("Wert2: " + sollWert2);
                System.out.println("Wert3: " + sollWert3);
                System.out.println("Wert4: " + sollWert4);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the strings from a particular iteration through the loop, some kind of collection, or some kind of concatenation? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Store them in a list of some custom object.

Comment: Move the declarations out of the loop.

Comment: @ktb - That would just provide the strings from the last iteration through the loop.

Comment: and this is in the same class but later on, sorry im new to java =( came from vba :D

Comment: @Andy I think you are assuming what he wants. I'm starting a convo to get a better question out of him.

Comment: @ktb - I've explicitly asked what he or she wants -- and observed that your suggestion makes an assumption.

Comment: @AndyThomas i need  the Strings to compare textfield strings with it so the text field strings are not in the loop :( i think i need the strings public / global

Comment: @Andy Yes I did. New users/programmers, desperate for an answer, tend to just try things. They can't formulate a better question because they can't. You give them something simple, let them tell you that solution is wrong, then get more info. But it's a presumption to think that any particular initial guess is wrong.

Comment: @terades - Do you want to compare the `sollWert1` etc. values *from each line* to the text field strings?

Comment: Yes i get substrings from my TextField and compare each one of them with sollWert1, sollWert2....

Comment: @Andy Thomas ohh in the text field is every time only 1 line of code !:D

Comment: @AndyThomas text file i mean

Comment: If you want to compare the `sollWert1` etc values from each line, even when there's only one line, **then you could leave the comparison inside the loop over lines.** If you know there's exactly one line, you don't need to loop over lines at all.

Comment: @ktb - Reread my comment. I did not say your suggestion was wrong. I observed a limitation to it. You made an assumption, and I noted it. You'll find this polite honesty common on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Define a global list in your program

```
List<String> werts = new ArrayList<>();
....................
....................
String[] parts = line.split(";");
for(String part : parts){
    werts.add(part);
}
```

Then you can use the elements in `werts`, and after that clear it if you need to go through the file another time (optional)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't do processing directly within your `main()` method. At least create an instance of the enclosing class (use `new ReadText()`) and put the code within some processing method of the class (i.e. `public void process() { ... }`).

Objects in Java are used, among other reasons, because they have **state**. Then, you can define private properties for your `ReadText` object and store the values read in there (for example, do have a `protected String sollWert1` etc.)

And finally, if you are intending to keep an unknown number of values for later usage, use a `List` (if you need ordering and don't need to label them), `Set` (if you're not concerned about order) or `Map` (if you want them labeled). Generally, using variable names like `something1`, `something2`, `something3` etc. implies that you want to use a data structure instead.